# How do you loop a path animation?

Tags: animation, fcurves, curve-modifier, looping

I am trying to loop an animation using the F-Curve Modifier. So far, it works for objects that have keyframe data, however, it does not work on the curve object that controls the animation of other objects and I need help looping that part of the animation. If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Objects that are being animated]

Comment: Does [this](https://imgur.com/a/PulY7vZ) help? [End Result](https://imgur.com/a/3S0UiR4)